# How to make the CentOS 7.3 to execute a php file every three minutes?

Tags: linux, centos

Under CentOS 7.3, I want to to execute a php file every three minutes.

And it should be thread safety.

But I don't know how to do with that.

The path is :

```
/Home/Controller/xy28.php
```

**Update**
path is:

```
/opengame/Application/Home/Controller/xy28.php
```

Comment: crontab -e and then */3 * * * * /usr/bin/php /Home/Controller/xy28.php finally press esc and :wq enter

Comment: @LittleSmurfie I am not that  familiar with Linux, Can you explain more about it? bro. thanks very much, I use Xmanager.

Comment: I assume that you have a terminal for any user and php installed. First run "crontab -e" command. This will open a text editor like vim. Then press "i". This will take you to insert mode. Type this "*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/php /Home/Controller/xy28.php" then press "Esc" button. This will take you to command mode. Finally in command mode press ":" right after "wq" then press "Enter". Now we set a scheduled task for the user you logged in to terminal. Again I assume the user have the proper rights to accomplish that php script.

Comment: @LittleSmurfie My friend, when I follow your steps to the last step, after I press 'Enter', I got the error:`no crontab for root - using an empty one
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.oD7RUA":1: bad hour
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? `

Comment: @LittleSmurfie Please help me, my bro, I am struggle with it.

Comment: @LittleSmurfie I success, somewhere I write error.

Comment: You might have type the content incorrectly. I think you achieved the task.

Comment: @LittleSmurfie When I :wq from the file, there shows:`[root@localhost Controller]# crontab -e
crontab: installing new crontab
[root@localhost Controller]# `. does it success ?

Comment: @LittleSmurfie How to detect if I success? How to know if it is running per 3 minutes?

Comment: If it says "installing new crontab". It was correct. You can check all the scheduled tasks by running "crontab -l" command. You can view the details of what happened while task were running, by reading the /var/log/cron file. "cat /var/log/cron"

Comment: @LittleSmurfie if I use the `*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/php /Home/Controller/xy28.php` instruct, if is there have thread-safety hidden danger？

Comment: @LittleSmurfie Hi, my bro. I have a question about that：the whole path of xy28.php is `xxx/home/wwwroot/Application/Home/Controller/xy28.php`. Can I use the `*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/php usr/home/wwwroot/opengame/Application/Home/Controller/xy28.php`? or should I use `*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/php /opengame/Application/Home/Controller/xy28.php`

Comment: You need to pass the argument as full path. I mean the second one you wrote must be working properly.

Comment: do you mean the `usr/home/wwwroot/opengame/Application/Home/Controller/xy28.p‌​hp` ?

Comment: Hey, you can figure it out by trying. And now I will write more valuable info; there is a command which is called "man", giving you the all information about the command and the usage of it very easy: "man name_of_command". You must learn actual meanings of RTFM and JFGI.